# How to find a filename using wildcards?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I use a cmd batch command to find a filename using wildcard matching?

I want to run the following, where the wildcard should match the one file that is contained in the dir:

```
SET FILENAME=c:\my-example-file-*.jar
java -jar %FILENAME%
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is always one, just use a listing:

```
FOR %%F IN (c:\my-example-file-*.jar) DO java -jar %%F
```